# Cannot download "pecl/mongodb" (Connection to `ssl://pecl.php.net:443' failed: )

Tags: php, mongodb, docker, docker-compose, pecl

I am seeing this issue after running docker-compose up command. I am new to docker that is why, I have no idea what's going on here and how to fix this issue.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I1bPF.png)

I executed docker-compose command to build and run docker container but in middle I got an unknown error.

Comment: Did you follow the instructions in the error? `apt-install php-pear`.

Comment: To add on to the last comment, you were also suggested to run `pecl channel-update pecl.php.net `